# EF6: Extend Db.Context.cs file

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I am trying implement Full Text search in EF6 following this [guide](http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch)

As per the guide following has to be added:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new FtsInterceptor());
    }
    public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NoteMap());
    }
}
```

However I would like to extend the auto generated `Db.Context.cs` code:

```
public partial class smartDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public smartDBEntities()
        : base("name=smartDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

**NOTE:** One cannot simply edit the Db.Context.cs file as it is auto generated when the database template changes

**UPDATE:** It seems that `OnModelCreating` function is only used in `CodeFirstModel` and in `DatabaseFirstModel` `OnModelCreating` would not be called, hence there is an exception thrown `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` 
So the sub question now is where to put `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NoteMap());`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend your `DbContext` using the partial class approach, then your base class **also** must be a `public partial class`, and the extension class must be of the **same name**:

"Base" `DbContext` (in your `generated\MyContext.cs` file):

```
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
         DbInterception.Add(new FtsInterceptor());
    }

    public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        // ....
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NoteMap());
    }
}
```

and your "extension" class must look like (in a **separate**, `custom\MyContext.cs` file):

```
public partial class MyContext 
{
    // define other, additional methods here
}
```

**Update:** since you want to basically "extend" the code in the `OnModelCreating` method - why not just **descend** from that basic `DbContext`??

```
public partial class MyContextEx : MyContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
}
```

and then use the `MyContextEx` context in your code??

Comment: In the answer you are modifying the auto-generated class. However, we don't want to modify the auto-generated class as it would be over-written when there is any change in the database model. So I wonder if we can have similar functions in 2 partial class one overriding the other as you suggest.

Comment: @ShyamalParikh: no, I'm **extending** the class - this part of the code can reside in a separate `.cs` file in another directory where the generated code doesn't get generated into ! Those two **separate** files on disk are combined by the compiler into a **single class** `MyContext`

Comment: I get your point what I am saying is `generated\MyContext.cs` contains different code under `OnModelCreating` function. So if I repeat the same function with different code (check question) in `custom\MyContext.cs` wouldn't it cause conflict?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh: why would you **repeat** that code?? Your custom partial class **only** contains **additional, new code** - it doesn't replicate the original file.....

Comment: Please checkout the code in question the `generated` partial class contains `OnModelCreating` function while the custom partial class also has `OnModelCreating` function however, the code within is different

Comment: @ShyamalParikh: ok, that's even easier - just **descend** from your generated context and define the additional statements in your custom class ....

Comment: Ok it seems that `OnModelCreating` function is only used in `CodeFirstModel` in `DatabaseFirst` it would not be called hence there is an exception thrown `throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();` Which means I don't know where to put `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NoteMap());` anymore :(